# Laravel rest api (santum) for mobile application

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, mobile, laravel-sanctum

I have created a REST API with LARAVEL SANCTUM. I have tested api on postman and it works as expected but when mobile developer uses it on ionic app, it returns for login "TOKEN MISMATCH".

Here is my API route

```
Route::post('/register', [ApiController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/login', [ApiController::class, 'login']);
```

Here is the ApiController for login

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $fields = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8'            
    ]);

    //validate login parameters
    //check email
    $user = User::where('email', $fields['email'])->first();

    //check password
    if(!$user || !Hash::check($fields['password'], $user->password)){
        return response([
            'message' => 'Invalid Credentials'
        ], 401);
    }

    $token = $user->createToken('myapptoken')->plainTextToken;
    //return $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;

    $response = [
        'user' => $user,
        'token' =>$token,
    ];

    return response($response, 201);
}
```

EndPoint: https://findajob.ng/api/login

Email:johndeo1@gmail.com
Password: 12345678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be a problem from `backend`, but in other-hand, if everything work in postman, you might try to:

1. Change `support_credentials` in `config\cors` to true.
2. Add `withCredential` header to front-end.